# vote counter updating with Ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am creating a voting system with Ajax and the vote counter would show the result dynamically. I can create the vote and delete the vote with Ajax successfully. However, I could not update the vote counter dynamically. I did a lot of trial and error and running out of options.

`<div id="counter"><%= @micropost.thumbups.count %></div>`, in a div with id, counter, shows vote numbers correctly on microposts/show page.

On create.js.erb,

```
$("#ups_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('microposts/down_form')) %>")

$("#counter").html('<%= @micropost.thumbups.count %>')
```

The second line is supposed to make the counter to update count dynamically after Ajax has successfully updated the database. But it did not work.

I tried with the following:

1. `$("#counter").html('hello')`, "hello" would show. this means CSS is fine.
2. `$("#counter").html('<%=escape_javascript @micropost.thumbups.count %>')` did not work.
3. `$("#counter").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('microposts/count')) %>")`, after making a count partial of `<%= @micropost.thumbups.count %>`
4. ...don't know what else to try...

Comment: Ruby 2.1, rails 4.2. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$("#counter").html('');
$("#counter").html('<%= j @micropost.thumbups.count %>');
```

Comment: `j` is an alias for `escape_javascript`.

Comment: It does not work. Any other ideas? Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Your association is probably already loaded in to memory. Try this:

```
$("#counter").html('<%= @micropost.thumbups(:reload).count %>')
```

Comment: It does not work. Neither $("#counter").html('<%= @micropost.thumbups.count(:reload) %>'), or $("#counter").html('<%= @micropost(:reload).thumbups.count %>'). Any other ideas? Thanks for helping!

Comment: Are you sure that the thumbsup saved? In your Rails console, run `Thumbups.count` to see how many there are. Then try to save a thumbs up. Then run `Thumbups.count` again. Are you sure it went up?

Comment: Yes. I am pretty sure the entry of thumbups is shown in my PostgreSQL 9.3 database with pgAdmin III. Besides, the counter can show the correct number of thumbups with <div id="counter"><%= @micropost.thumbups.count %></div> in microposts/show page if I refresh the browser. However, I want the counter to show new entry of thumbups without refreshing the browser. This is what Ajax is all about, isn't it?

Comment: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users, I am building a similar app based on Michael Hartl's example. I got follow users or unfollow users and the number shows dynamically without a problem. By following the same logic, I thought I could build a counter updating the thumbups dynamically as well. Don't what went wrong...